# How to get specific array elements from multidimensional array in JavaScript With dynamic params?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've multidimensional associative array.

In some cases I'll need only ID, Name & In some cases I'll need only Name, Email. so is it possible to pass dynamic parameters ?

So how will use with dynamic parameters ?

```
[
  {
    'ID': 1,
    'Name': 'Sorav',
    'Email': 'sorav@email.com',
    'Phone': '9090909090'
  },
  {
    'ID': 2,
    'Name': 'Gaurav',
    'Email': 'gaurav@email.com',
    'Phone': '9696969696'
  }
]
```

In above array, I want to fetch only two elements (ID & Name).

So is there any predefined function in JavaScript ? Or how we can achieve that ?

Please let me know.

Comment: do you want an array of all objects with the wanted properties?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr =[
  {
    'ID': 1,
    'Name': 'Sorav',
    'Email': 'sorav@email.com',
    'Phone': '9090909090'
  },
  {
    'ID': 2,
    'Name': 'Gaurav',
    'Email': 'gaurav@email.com',
    'Phone': '9696969696'
  }
]

const res = arr.map(item => {
  return {
    ID: item['ID'],
    Name: item['Name']
  }
})

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Can we use  achieve this using loadsh library ?  I've dynamic elements

Comment: In some cases I'll need only ID, Name & In some cases I'll need only Name, Email. so is it possible to pass dynamic parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using `map`

```js
var input = [
  {
    'ID': 1,
    'Name': 'Sorav',
    'Email': 'sorav@email.com',
    'Phone': '9090909090'
  },
  {
    'ID': 2,
    'Name': 'Gaurav',
    'Email': 'gaurav@email.com',
    'Phone': '9696969696'
  }
];

var output = input.map(x => ({ID:x.ID,Name:x.Name}));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Can we use  achieve this using loadsh library ?  I've dynamic elements

Comment: @SoravGarg looks like the linked duplicate does exactly what you're after

Answer (score 0):

With map and deconstruction it's a simple task

```js
const  input = [
  {
    'ID': 1,
    'Name': 'Sorav',
    'Email': 'sorav@email.com',
    'Phone': '9090909090'
  },
  {
    'ID': 2,
    'Name': 'Gaurav',
    'Email': 'gaurav@email.com',
    'Phone': '9696969696'
  }
];

const output = input.map(({ID, Name}) => ({ID, Name}))
console.log(output)
```